# How can access the site only through its IP

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site, say `www.test.com`. Now I need to get see the site only by typing the IP address, i.e. `102.3.0.2/index.php`.

For that, what I need to change in my htaccess file?

Following is my htaccess file code:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /cash-flights/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !(^index\.php|gif$|jpg$|jpeg$|JPG$|JPEG$|GIF$|PNG$|BMP$|png$|bmp$|js$|php$|htm$|html$|css$|ttf$|txt$|pdf$|swf$|flv$|robots\.txt$|video_chat$|.ico$)
#RewriteRule ^(?!js\/tinymce)(.*?)(\.html|\.php|\/)?$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(?!phpinfo\.php)(?!js\/tinymce)(?!turkeyMap)(?!cron_home)(?!quote_by_sms)(?!paypal)(?!supporttrio)(?!12all)(?!system\/application\/libraries\/libgmap)(.*?)(\.html|\.php|\/)?$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [NC,L] 

#php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

deny from 100.200.200.200
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is the reason why you are not getting it, but the ip has to be four numbers. 
I.E. 102.1.10.1.

Any site name ex: www.test.com must be translated to an ip, if you can reach the site using a name you can also reach it using the ip address.

Comment: but if iam trying to accesss the site through ip, then its redirecting to wwww, asper the code in .htaccess.So how can i change?

Comment: Maybe `102.3.02` was meant to be `102.3.0.2` because that leading zero in `02` is not really legal either.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=123.456.789.101
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://123.456.789.101$1 [R,L]
```

But it can easily be bypassed by editing the value of the `HOST` HTTP header.

Comment: Do i need to add this code snippet only,Do i need  remove any code from the existing .htaccess.Let me know , where 123.456.789.101 is the ip of server?

Comment: Yes, `123.456.789.101` "should be" the IP address of your server. You need to add that code after the line `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: And i need to remove the existing code RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] from the .htaccess file, right?

Comment: You may remove it, but it's not *necessary*.

Comment: I have tried in that way.But iam getting 500 server error ie           Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@everydaydirect.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.